# plotTSNE to show gene distribution in a population of cells (scRNAseq)

Tags: r

I have a set of single cell RNAseq data with a SCEset format and used sc3 package to perform clustering analysis.

Code:

```
Count <- sc3_prepare(Data, ks = 2:5)
Count <- sc3_estimate_k(Count)
Count@sc3$k_estimation
Count <- sc3(Count, ks = 5, biology = TRUE)
```

It is easy to use `plotTSNE` function to show the tSNE plot. However, I don't know how to plot the distribution of a specific gene expression in the tSNE plot.

[image]

I tried the following code but it didn't work:

```
tsne_colplot <- function(gene_name) {
  df <- as.numeric(Data[grep(paste0("^",gene_name,"$"),rownames(Data)),])
  col <- c("lightgray","orange","red")
  colAlpha <- add.alpha(col, alpha=0.1)
  (colc <- cut(df, breaks = c(0, 1, 100, Inf), include.lowest = TRUE))

  plotTSNE(Count, rand_seed = 123456, colour_by = col[colc], main=gene_name) 
}

add.alpha <- function(col, alpha=1) {
  if(missing(col))
    stop("Please provide a vector of colours.")
  apply(sapply(col, col2rgb)/255, 2, function(x)
    rgb(x[1], x[2], x[3], alpha=alpha))
}
```

Comment: can't you use Rtsne and plot.Rtsne directly?

Comment: It would seem to me that in your `tsne_colplot` function you're trying to plot a graph per gene, rather than the gene set. The plotTSNE function takes all the genes in your set and if your expression set is contained in a scater object you can colour and group directly by feature. Have a look at: https://hemberg-lab.github.io/scRNA.seq.course/data-visualization.html#visual-tsne

Comment: I can directly use Rtsne to plot. But it yields different tSNE plot from the one generated from plotTSNE. Indeed, I want to show the cells with marker gene expression on the tSNE plot.